# java: add a file to a jar directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, processbuilder

I am working on a project which requires users to upload a Java file which can be later compiled into a class file. I have already written the code for uploading the file to the project folder. It works perfectly when launched using Eclipse. The problem arises when I package the project as a JAR. The code throws an exception. I understand the reason.. when we package the project, only the class files are loaded in JAR and not the source files, and the location of the JAR file also makes a difference.

Let me explain what I have done and what I need to do:

In the IDE version of the project, I have something like:
[image]
where the user can browse for a file and click on the upload button to add it to the project structure. This works perfectly with the following code:

```
String path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()+"\\path\\to\\directory";
File source=new File(textField1.getText());
String fileName="";
try {
    fileName=new java.io.File(textField1.getText()).getName();
    Files.copy(source.toPath(),new java.io.File(path+fileName).toPath(),REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I have to run the same code using a JAR file, I understand that I am supposed to change how I fetch the root directory of the project and then navigate to the required directory. Somehow, I can't get it working. I have already tried the following:

```
URL location=MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String p = URLDecoder.decode(location.getFile(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(location);
```

This prints `rsrc:./`. How can I copy the uploaded file to the required directory  within the Jar file?

I also tried another approach where I thought of creating a shell script to execute `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`. I put the JAR file and this shell script in the same directory, and execute the following code:

```
try {
        String fileName = "shellFile.sh";
        URL location=MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String p = URLDecoder.decode(location.getFile(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(location);
        String inputFilePath = p + fileName;
        System.out.println(inputFilePath);
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I get the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./shellFile.sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Is there any way I can upload a file to a directory within the JAR file?

Comment: Any .jar file in the runtime classpath should be considered read-only.  As you’ve discovered, there is no guarantee those .jar files will be physical files at all.

Comment: I can ensure that the packages are present. If I close the jar file and run `jar uf jar-file.jar input-file.java`, it works fine. What I can not figure out it how to do this programatically from the jar file itself.

Comment: That’s irrelevant.  At runtime, a ClassLoader’s internal implementation can provide the classes however it wishes.  You cannot reliably assume the .jar files will be available as files *at runtime.*  And even in cases where they are files, you cannot reliably assume you’ll be able to modify them.  In particular, I’ve observed that the Windows versions of Java keep each runtime .jar file locked.

Comment: I understand. Windows OS indeed locks the jar file during execution and this is evident from the error received on running the `jar uf jar-file input-filè`command. I don't think there is a viable solution for my problem. I should maybe think of adding the compiled .class file before running the jar file itself. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String cmd = "jar uvf " + <jar file name> + " " + <name of file to be added;
System.out.println(cmd);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```